# Take derivatives without changing variable orders

Tags: python, sympy

I need to take the first-order derivative of a dataset then sum-product with another dataset. df can be any dataset with variables of 'coe'

```
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative
coe=['x1', 'x1x1', 'y1x1', 'y2x1', 'x1x2', 'x1t']
c=[df[0]]+[c[2:]+"*" + c[0:2] for c in df[1:]]
f="+".join(c)
##I then take the first-order derivative useing###
var = Symbol("x1")
deriv= Derivative(f, var)
equ=deriv.doit()
```

I expecting '1 + 2*x1 + y1 + y2 + x2 + t', but obtained 't + 2*x1 + x2 + y1 + y2 + 1'.

Since the variable names changed after taking the derivatives and I think I can only get the sum-products of the derivatives and a list of coefficients by the variable positions. Can anyone guide how to keep the variable order unchanged? or if you have another idea to carry out sum-products of two datasets with unmatched feature names. Many thanks.
*sq is square and transferred to x1x1 in the instance.

```
df=  {'variable' :['t',
     'tsq',
     'y1'
     'y2'
      'x1'
     'x2'
   'y1sq'
    'y2sq'
    'x1sq'
   'x2sq'
   'y1y2'
    'y1x1'
   'y1x2'
    'y1t'
    'y2x1'
   'y2x2'
    'y2t'
    'x1x2'
   'x1t'
   'x2t'],  'coff':[0.122829,
-0.001988,
-0.640026,
-0.207242,
-0.216470,
0.543162,
-0.306203,
-0.073799,
0.021244,
0.217912,
0.044708,
-0.162187,
0.010670,
 0.019184,
-0.091513,
0.037395,
0.011135,
-0.026129,
-0.001651,
0.000157,
-0.635156,
-0.009173,
-1.022478]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You obtained what you expected, so what's the problem? Addition is commutative in SymPy.

Your code produces a `KeyError` with your example for `df`. If I used `df['variable']` or `df['coff']` in place of `df`, I still could not produce what you got. So I had to assume you are differentiating `coe` instead; in which case, the description about df was not necessary.

This is my solution for best understanding of your problem:

```py
from sympy import diff

coe = ['x1', 'x1x1', 'y1x1', 'y2x1', 'x1x2', 'x1t']

c = [coe[0]] + [line[2:] + "*" + line[0:2] for line in coe[1:]]
derivatives = [str(diff(value, "x1")) for value in c]
print(derivatives)
equ = "+".join(derivatives)
print(equ)
```

This produces results as expected.

---

If you get your Symbols via Twitter, then you should have them as symbols from the start and perform no string manipulation. This means that you can perform the older code shown below.

---

There are multiple strange things with your code and I don't think they were intentional:

- If `df = coe[1:]`, then the first element in `c` is `x1x1`. This is treated as a single variable by SymPy. That is, `x1x1` is not `x1**2`. Is this intentional from you?
- Datasets are almost never made up of strings. They use a lot of RAM and you can't do math with them directly. They are almost always 2 dimensional arrays as well.
- String manipulation should never be used for arithmetic operations. It is terrible to read, doesn't scale well (say you had `x10` in your dataset for example) and debugging is a massive struggle.
- Assigning `c` to a list comprehension that uses `c` is very confusing for whoever is reading your code.

The following is far more readable:

```py
from sympy import symbols, diff, prod

x1, x2, y1, y2, t = symbols("x1, x2, y1, y2, t", real=True)

# datasets are almost always 2D objects
coe = [[x1, 1],
       [x1, x1],
       [y1, x1],
       [y2, x1],
       [x1, x2],
       [x1, t]]

# df can be any subset of coe
# including any of the below:
# df = coe
# df = coe[1:]
df = [coe[1],
      coe[3],
      coe[2]]

products = [prod(line) for line in df]
sum_product = sum(products)
equ = diff(sum_product, x1)
print(equ)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. coe=['x1', 'x1x1', 'y1x1', 'y2x1', 'x1x2', 'x1t'] was obtained from previous dataset with ['x1','x2','y1','y2'], written up as x1x1 because the equation needs to be transformed to [x1+x1*2+y1*x1+y2*x1+t*x1] via c=[df[0]]+[c[2:]+"*" + c[0:2] for c in df[1:]]
f="+".join(c)

Comment: Yes, I got the derivatives I needed but in a different order, which I will be unable to do sun-product with another dataset containing coefficients for ['x1', 'x1x1', 'y1x1', 'y2x1', 'x1x2', 'x1t'] . My datasets are not strings, what was given is the variable names.

Comment: besides, 'x1y1' is one variable name obtained from x1*y1, cant be written as [x1,y1]. I am struggling with the order of variables after deriv= Derivative(f, var) to take sum-product. Sum-products should be taken after the derivatives not before. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to put my question clearer. I have two datasets, df contains coefficient values for ['x1', 'x1x1', 'y1x1', 'y2x1', 'x1x2', 'x1t'] , and coe is the value of ['x1', 'x1x1', 'y1x1', 'y2x1', 'x1x2', 'x1t'] . after taking derivative, I shall have [1,2x1, y1, y2, x2 ,t] taking sum-product with df. as all the variable names have changed after derivatives, I can only calculate sum-product based on positions, e.g, 1*df[0] given df[0] is the coefficient for x1.

Comment: @SHendricks, 1. If the sum-product must be taken after the derivative of `coe`, then why did you do it before and why did you differentiate `df` in your sample code? 2. If you wanted to refactor `x1` for example, your code would break because of your string manipulation. This shows bad practice. 3. Instead of defining your string, `'x1y1'`, you could have easily defined my list `[x1,y1]` with zero issues. 4. Is `df` a list of integers or a list of symbols? Niether `df` nor `coe` can be a list of strings because of point 2. Can you please provide your initialization of `df` in your question.

Comment: The only place you should have strings is in the line `x1, x2, ... = symbols('x1, x2, ...')`. If you are doing maths, then string manipulation makes little sense. Don't rely on SymPy's string parser. If you really wanted to keep your own code snippet and wanted the derivatives to keep their order then ignore everything I've previously said and put the following after your `c=...` line: `c = [diff(x, 'x1') for x in c]` and remove all lines after your comment. This will produce an `f` that you 'expect'. Don't forget to import `diff`.

Comment: 1. df is a dataframe of coefficients containing variables of [x1,x2,y1,y2,x1y1,x1y2.....]. They will be multiplied by the first order derivatives of another dataframe cow. If the position of variables of 'coe' changed after taking derivatives, the multiplying will be a disaster. I wrote a loop function for the code above as I need to take partical derivatives for x1, x2, y1,y2, respectively. 3. x1y1 can not be broken down to [x1,y1] as it contains one value of x1*y1. 4. df is a dataframe for integers. I will add the df values for your references.

Comment: I messaged Symbols via twitter, they said they cant make any changes for variable positions. Looking at the results I got, it looks like Sympy takes alphabetical orders. e.g. my function f='x1+x1*x1+x1*y1+x1*y2+x2*x1+t*x1', but Sympy automatically changed it to t*x1 + x1**2 + x1*x2 + x1*y1 + x1*y2 + x1, x1, then take derivatives. So all variable positions altered.

Comment: @SHendricks I have updated the solution that uses minimal changes to your code. If this is not what you wanted, then I cannot help you further as I clearly don't understand the question.

Comment: You couldn't understand the question because you are confused by the variables of x1y1, x1y2..., those are products of each x and y. Stochastic frontier is a bit of confusion. And those lists are columns names of my datasets, there are 2ds. I cant understand how could you see it 3d. Anyway, thanks for trying. You are the only person tried to help. I have sorted it out using another way, not Sympy.